# problems configuring qooxdoo Inspector component

Tags: qooxdoo

I am trying to configure the Inspector component as per instructions here: http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/application/inspector_selenium.html#pages-application-inspector-selenium-using-the-qooxdoo-inspector-to-write-selenium-tests

I am having problems following the configuration instructions, where it says to configure the Selenium window with the selenium-core zip file. I cannot find this file at the provided address: http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Any suggestions as to what I should use instead of that zip file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just press the "Use default URI" button in the Inspector's Selenium Options window and it will load the scripts from the Selenium SVN repository on Google Code. If that doesn't work for you it gets a bit complicated since the Inspector requires a deprecated version of Selenium:

Download Selenium RC from here and unpack it:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-remote-control-1.0.2.zip

Then extract 
selenium-remote-control-1.0.2/selenium-server-1.0.2/selenium-server-standalone-1.0.2.jar to a directory named e.g. "selenium-server" and enter the path to that directory in the Inspector's  Selenium Options window.